# Convert a ksqlDB MAP to ARRAY

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a ksqlDB column of `MAP<STRING, STRUCT>`
I'm looking for a way to convert it to `ARRAY<STRUCT>`

The function `ENTRIES()` looked like the right tool, but using it I got

```
Function 'ENTRIES' does not accept parameters (MAP<STRING, STRUCT<C STRING, D STRING>>).
Valid alternatives are:
ENTRIES(MAP<STRING, DOUBLE> map, BOOLEAN sorted)
ENTRIES(MAP<STRING, BOOLEAN> map, BOOLEAN sorted)
ENTRIES(MAP<STRING, VARCHAR> map, BOOLEAN sorted)
ENTRIES(MAP<STRING, BIGINT> map, BOOLEAN sorted)
ENTRIES(MAP<STRING, INT> map, BOOLEAN sorted)
```

Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

**update:**
The message I have looks something like this:

```
{"a":1, "b":{"b1": {"c":"aaa", "d":"bbb"}, "b2": {"c":"ccc", "d":"ddd"}}}
```

This is mapped to a schema like:

```
a INT,
b MAP<STRING, STRUCT<
  c STRING,
  d STRING
>>
```

The schema I would like to convert it to is:

```
a INT,
b ARRAY<STRUCT<
  c STRING,
  d STRING
>>
```

and the converted message should look like this:

```
{"a":1, "b":[{"c":"aaa", "d":"bbb"},{"c":"ccc", "d":"ddd"}]}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your source message and desired output?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I added more examples and details the the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like ksqlDB's `ENTRIES` supports this yet.

I would log an enhancement request at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new.

Comment: Thanks. Created https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5452